# Is the set of zero sets of rational coefficient polynomials countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that the set of algebraic numbers is countable. I have managed to prove that the set of rational coefficient polynomials is countable. My idea is to prove that the set of zero-sets of rational coefficient polynomials is countable and argue the algebraic numbers are a subset of that set. Here is my reasoning:

If we assume each polynomial of positive degree k has at most $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ roots (we assume this without proof), then for each $p \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ the set $P_0 = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q}\, |\, p(x) = 0 \}$ is countable (since the set is finite). If we let $\mathcal{P}$ be the collection of zero-sets, then the set of all zero-sets is
$\bigcup_{P_0 \in \mathcal{P}} P_0$. This is a countable union, since each zero set corresponds to a unique rational coefficient polynomial (the set of which is proven to be a countable set). Thus the set is a countable union of countable sets i.e countable. Is my argument correct?

NOTE: This is not for homework. This is for self studying. 
EDIT 2: polynomial of positive degree k

Comment: Well, we know each polynomial has at most $d$ roots where $d$ is the degree.  That's good enough.

Comment: @lulu But don't we need the fact that the union is specifically a countable union? At least the book I'm studying (Munkres Topology) states that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Sure.  There are countably many polynomials of degree $d$.  Each of them has at most $d$ roots.  Thus there are countably many algebraic numbers of degree $d$.  But every algebraic number has a degree.

Comment: This is false. Every real number is a zero of the zero polynomial.

Comment: @Shalop I've added the clarification, though it was implicit in the text that we consider positive degree polynomials, since the motivation for the proof regards algebraic numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is correct. Actually the number of roots of a polynomial in $\Bbb Q[X]$ is not greater than its degree. Note that if $\alpha$ is a root of $p(X)$ then $p(X)=q(X)(x-\alpha)$ for some polynomial $q$ and $\deg(q)=\deg(p)-1$.

Comment: Oops, didn't realise I missed the "less than degree" part. Thanks very much!